# WPF Reset Storyboard When Selecting Again

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, storyboard, expression-blend

How to set back a storyboard just like when the page is loaded? My situation here, at the same page I have 2 animation. For button A and button B. Both button will run a storyboard eg: NavigateMyCar_A and NavigateMyCar_B.

If I click button A, it will run a NavigateMyCar_A storyboard.
If I click button B, it will run a NavigateMyCar_B storyboard.

And if click back the button A, the storyboard will appear as the finish timeline. How do I reset back the position of the timeline? Below are what I do everytime it want to begin a storyboard but still on the last frame.

```
Dim mystoryboard As New Storyboard
mystoryboard = CType(Me.Resources("NavigateMyCar_A"), Storyboard)
mystoryboard.Seek(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime)
mystoryboard.Stop()
mystoryboard.Begin(Me)
```

- I already seek answer on google and tried it. And what I post here is what I try but not succeed. Kindly help. TQ

EDITED: After click button A, it will run another animation call "View_Animation" to view the result and user press button "NAVIGATE" and NavigateMyCar_A will start. Same function apply to button B. But when it comes back to button A, it will view result under "View_Animation" but the navigation of car A is finish already before hit the NAVIGATE button..I do animation after animation programatically

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use the `Begin` method with the `Me` passed in. So to control the Storyboard, you have to use the `Seek` method without that same containing element passed in. Something like this:

```
mystoryboard.Seek(Me, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime)
```

That's just simple like that. In case the `Begin` method is called like this `Begin()` (without any argument), then your original code will work.